# Python Using star (*)

Tags: python, syntax, definition

I am confused about using `*`. The `first_example` works, but why doesn't the `second_example` work?

The error states:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

What can I do to fix this error?

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = range(1,10)
alphabet = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]

def first_example(*alphabet):
    j = g + i
    print (j)
    second_example(*alphabet)

def second_example(*alphabet):
    a = a + 1
    print (a)

first_example(*alphabet)
```

Comment: The `*` isn't the problem. `a = a + 1` is

Comment: What can I do to fix it?

Comment: add 'global a' in second_example().

Comment: Note that neither of your functions actually do anything with their `alphabet` parameter. The `alphabet` parameter is not involved in any way with variable lookup for `a`, `g`, `i`, or any of the other variables.

Comment: Your first_example() works because you're creating a new variable called 'j' and only reading 'g' and 'i'. But since you're trying to read _and_ modify 'a' -- not defined in the scope of your function second_example(), you'd have to add the 'global' keyword.

Comment: Looks like you stumbled upon python's (non-C-like) scoping rules. See: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php for a good explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do (since `alphabet` parameter is unused), or why you think `*` is the issue, but this'll fix the problem.

```
def second_example(*alphabet):
    global a  # add this
    a = a + 1
    print (a)
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and works like a charm!